# Cannot set boolean to null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a class Shop with the following variable

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "bit")
private boolean atShop;
```

Using this value, I am using HSQL to retrieve this information from the application

```
from Person person
left join fetch person.shop
```

when I try call this HSQL statement i get the following error

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of com.test.dataobject.Shop.atShop; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of com.test.dataobject.Shop.atShop
```

It is throwing this because it is trying to set the boolean to null in the HSQL. I can solve this problem by changing `private boolean atShop;` to `private Boolean atShop;` but i want to keep this as a `boolean` as i am saving it as a bit in my database

Is there a way to solve this without changing `boolean` to `Boolean`?

**EDIT:**

I know that boolean can only be true/false and Boolean can be set to null, but is there a way to get hibernate/spring to set this value to false(which i thought it should do automatically) instead of trying to set it to null and throwing this exception?

I have also tried adding annotation to automatically set the value to false but this does not work either

```
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bit default 0")
private boolean atShop;
```

Comment: yes I know the differences between boolean and Boolean, my application is throwing this exception because spring/hibernate is trying to set atShop to null instead of false, but how can i get it to set it to false and not null?

Comment: Gee, I hate it when people downvote answers without any explanation and only because they are not exactly what they are looking for. Above all in a question like this which was not originally clear enough. It makes me lose my will to try to help.

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo: But it was not me who down voted the answers, that is why i added the edit section to my question because it was my fault that i did not explain that i already understood the differences between boolean and Boolean

Comment: As soon as I know, boolean in the database will be mapped as 1 or 0, so you don't need columnDefinition. If you want to be sure, you can add the mapping in the persistence file like that <property name="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0</property>

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**-** `boolean` is a **primitive type**, and can have a value of only `true or false`.

**-** Whereas `Boolean` is a **Wrapper Object** and can be given a **null** value.

**-** From `Java 1.5` `AutoBoxing` is provided, so you can **convert boolean to Boolean and back to boolean with Simple assignment operator** (`=`), So you can do this in places where you want Boolean instead of boolean.

Comment: `AutoBoxing` (i.e. boolean --> Boolean) always works just fine. But what you really should be careful with is `AutoUnboxing` (i.e. Boolean --> boolean), because it throws NullPointerException if your Boolean wrapper object is null. Usually, using something like `BooleanUtils.isTrue()` or `Boolean.TRUE.equals()` is a good idea, when you need to unbox a wrapper Boolean object in an NPE-safe manner.

Answer (score 12):

Rather than fiddle with the hibernate code, change your table definition to default null values to false (or 0). That way when you come to read from the database it will always have valid values (which, since it's boolean, makes more sense)

Comment: i tried updating the column in the table to have a default value of 0 (`ALTER TABLE Shop
ALTER COLUMN atShop bit NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)`) but i still get the same error

Comment: You probably need to fix all the values that you've currently saved, they will be null. You should set the column to be NOT NULL too.

Comment: i ended up completely dropping the column from the table and adding it back in using `ALTER TABLE Shop
ADD atShopbit NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)` and even though all the values are set to 0 and everything looks ok the error is still appearing

Comment: @HipHipArray For the existing column try `ALTER TABLE Shop ADD DEFAULT 0 FOR atShop`.

Answer (score 4):

`null` is not the same as `false` (nor is it the same as `true`).  `null` has a very specific meaning.  That is why Hibernate does what it does... because it is really the only thing that makes sense, despite what you think it should do.

If you want to instruct Hibernate to treat `null` in those columns as false, the only real solution is to develop a custom Hibernate Type mapping for this special treatment of "null is not really a null".  You can accomplish that by either implementing the `org.hibernate.type.Type` interface, or the `org.hibernate.usertype.UserType` interface.  You best bet is to extend the standard boolean Type mapping and weave in the special null handling.

One thing to be careful of, however, is querying since checking equality against `null` is never valid in ANSI SQL.  It resolves to what SQL calls `UNDEFINED`, which usually means `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

`boolean` is primitive it could be `true` or `false` and default is `false`. To obtain `null`, it's object type is `Boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd give my 2 cents on this since I had a similar issue but the solution was different.

So my issue was that it was retrieving data from the database and trying to save that data back. The data it retrieved for the boolean field was null. So when it tried to save it back it complained that it can't save null to a boolean.

The fix was to update the database data so none of these fields had null values.

Answer (score -1):

You do know you could just put a try catch around it if it throws an exception that means it was null, therefore set it to false.

Comment: That works if you're in control of the code where the assignment is done but in this case the OP is getting values from Hibernate, which does all the assignments and mappings for you, so without implementing his own Type handler for Hibernate, as mentioned in Steve Ebersole's answer above, this is not really an option