# error: incomparable types: boolean and <null>

Tags: java, android

```
if(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("mybool") == null)
```

I get error `error: incomparable types: boolean and <null>`

I want to check if mybool does not exist, how do I do  that?

My onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);}
```

Elsewhere in my code:

```
savedInstanceState.putBoolean("mybool", true);
```

Comment: Why would a boolean ever be null?

Comment: @tnw you get what I mean

Comment: @tnw I want to check if it exists

Comment: you want something like `if(savedInstanceState!=null && savedInstanceState.getboolean("mybool") == true){ // execute your code }`

Comment: @tnw just so you know, a bool can be null if it doesn't exist...

Comment: @JonathanDoe That makes no sense. An object that doesn't exist simply doesn't exist.

Comment: @tnw then how do I check if `savedInstanceState.getBoolean("mybool")` exists? that's my question

Comment: how do I check if it has been defined?? @tnw nobody's answering...

Comment: I'm not sure. You've provided no context about `savedInstanceStace` or `getBoolean`. What does `getBoolean` return when it does not exist? Try it and find out then handle that case appropriately.

Comment: The method returns a value -- its value exists, or else the method will throw an exception. And if it's a boolean, the value has just two states, true and false. There is no third "does not exist" state. So the value does exist, and the question you should be asking is, what is it.

Comment: @yshavit just tell me what to do

Comment: Probably just `if(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("mybool") {...`, but it's impossible to know for sure, since you haven't given us details on how that getBoolean works.

Comment: The issue you are running into is the fact that a primitive type boolean cannot be null. Even if you define it but do not set it, the variable has a value. All primitive variables are assigned a value when created even if you do not assign it a value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot set boolean to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013227/cannot-set-boolean-to-null)

Comment: @rabbitguy what's that initia value?

Comment: @JonathanDoe it's false.  See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @JonathanDoe I'm starting to detect a serious lack of effort here. For example, `just tell me what to do` despite numerous suggestions and not even bothering to google `java initial value boolean`. As a side note, whining about downvotes is not productive. Maybe take a second look at your question to see if it could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether `"mybool"` exists in the `Bundle` object:

```
if (!savedInstanceState.containsKey("mybool")) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.containsKey(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: i get crash now

Comment: it just crashes, please fix it

Comment: If you read the link I posted, you will learn how to fix it yourself :-)

Comment: i tried `if (!savedInstanceState.containsKey("mybool") && savedInstanceState.containsKey("mybool") != null)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: i will accept this answer once the problem is fixed

Comment: @JonathanDoe Don't comment spam! Other people don't have as much time as you might think. Many people work during the week or are simply not at their computers the whole time. Just wait until he gets to it. Being pushy and impatient won't help you get your answers faster.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle.html#getBoolean(java.lang.String)) say that `getBoolean(String key)` returns a `boolean`, i.e. a **primitive type**. Primitive types are never `null`. In this case it's either `true` or `false`. Compared to the **wrapper type** `Boolean`, which *can* be `null`.

Furthermore, the docs say if the key isn't present, this method simply returns `false`.

If you want to check if `mybool` exists or not, use `containsKey(String key)` instead. (Again, refer to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle.html#containsKey(java.lang.String)))

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Boolean instead of boolean i.e. use the Class instead if the primitive type. I do not recommend this though. Boolean should be either true or false.

Comment: excuse me? should I use this? if(savedInstanceState.getboolean("mybool") == null)

Comment: Can you define the structure of Bundle?

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: see my question

Answer (score 0):

This issue you are having is your understanding of how primitives work. Primitive types, including boolean, cannot be null. Even if you do not assign a value to them when you define the variable, there is a value assigned to them.

In the case of the primitive type boolean, the value is assigned as false when initialized if you do not assign a boolean value to the variable. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for more information on how primitives are treated and what their default values are.